# How to find best MLE using `FindDistributionParameters`

Tags: fitting, distributions

This question is an extension of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28793/problem-in-finddistributionparameters) question, if we change the initial values `FindDistributionParameters[data1, dist, {{a, 0.1}, {b, 0.1}, {c, 
   0.1}, {al, 0.1}, {be, 0.1}, {ph, 0.1}}]`
 to `FindDistributionParameters[data1, dist, {{a, 0.2}, {b, 0.1}, {c, 
   0.1}, {al, 0.1}, {be, 0.1}, {ph, 0.1}}]` parameter estimates also change. So my question is if we have no idea about initial values then how we search best initial values or best MLE estimates which close to empirical distribution of `data1`.
The empirical distribution with two parameters which are estimated with initial value's given above are plotted as

[image]

Not a best fit. The code of above plot is:

> data1 = {275, 13, 147, 23, 181, 30, 65, 10, 300, 173, 106, 300, 300, 
>      212, 300, 300, 300, 2, 261, 293, 88, 247, 28, 143, 300, 23, 300, 
>      80, 245, 266};
>   g1 = NIntegrate[(2.51339*2.51952*3.21532)/Beta[2.87484, 0.0825351]*
>       y^-(3.21532 + 1)*(1 + 
>         0.0609138*2.51952*y^-3.21532)^-((2.87484*2.51339)/0.0609138 + 
>          1)*(1 - (1 + 0.0609138*2.51952*y^-3.21532)^-(2.51339/
>           0.0609138))^(0.0825351 - 1), {y, 0, x}];
>
> g2 = NIntegrate[(1.98156*1.98026*3.2635)/Beta[2.64639, 0.090212]*
>       y^-(3.2635 + 1)*(1 + 
>         0.0328252*1.98026*y^-3.2635)^-((2.64639*1.98156)/0.0328252 + 
>          1)*(1 - (1 + 0.0328252*1.98026*y^-3.2635)^-(1.98026/
>           0.0328252))^(0.090212 - 1), {y, 0, x}];
>
> Plot[{g1, g2, CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[data1], x]}, {x, 2, 400},
>   Exclusions -> None]

Comment: Do you have the generating functions of your plots?

Comment: I add code in question

Answer (score 1):

Simply compare the value of loglikelihood of your estimates....

```
A = FindDistributionParameters[data1, dist, {{a, 0.1}, {b, 0.1}, {c, 0.1}, {al, 0.1}, {be, 0.1}, {ph,  0.1}}]

B = FindDistributionParameters[data1,  dist, {{a, 0.2}, {b, 0.1}, {c, 0.1}, {al, 0.1}, {be, 0.1}, {ph, 0.1}}]

LogLikelihood[dist /. A, data1]
-211.801

LogLikelihood[dist /. B, data1]
-212.959
```

So `A` is slightly a better fit.

Comment: `LogLikelihood` tell us in two parameter estimates which one is the best, but my question is still stand which fit is best among all range of parameters `a,b,c,al,be,ph>0'.

Comment: I would recommend you to run a table with multiple parameters as the starting values then compare the loglikelihood of all of them!!